# Where in opensolaris I can change ptlib/sunaudio settings?

Tags: opensolaris

Where in OpenSolaris can I change ptlib/sunaudio settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For configuring ekiga task i found another solution without changing ptlib/sunaudio settings. Question closed.